# Facebook style auto loading

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

We are developing a free, open source Google Reader alternative at http://reader.pykih.com and the code is at http://github.com/pykih/reader

When a user signs up or adds a RSS feed, we add the feed url to the database and then ask a DelayedJob to fetch articles from that RSS url. This typically takes few seconds to minute or two, depending on the DelayedJob queue. Many users have complained that RSS feed is not being fetched at all when in reality it is being fetched. All that the user has to do is refresh his own page. We wrote a message there, yet users are complaining.

Can anyone point us in direction towards - what is the best way to design a Facebook or Google style "Loading" (icon in yellow) functionality and once loaded it automatically adds the entries to the screen without page refresh.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Load the page with `Loading...`, then use a `setTimeout()` to check if it has loaded using Ajax. One Ajax returns something relevant, replace it in the page, and unregister the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you basically want to update the user's view of the page while it's still open, in real time. (At any rate, that's what Facebook and most Google products do nowadays). This technique is usually called *server push* - information is pushed from the server to the client, instead of having the client request (pull) information from the server.

There are multiple ways to implement server push.

- You could use AJAX to 'reload' the page every ten seconds or so. This is very easy to implement, but not realtime at all, and could cause unneeded load on your server. It works with all browsers.
- You could use EventSource, a relatively new format supported by Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and others (but not IE). It's a very simple format and [easy to implement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). EventSource is one-way communication only: it sends events from the server to the client, not in reverse.
- You could use WebSockets, probably using a library like EventMachine and a [WebSocket library](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket). WebSockets allow fast bidirectional communication, but it's more complex than EventSource and [only the newest IE versions support it](http://caniuse.com/websockets).
- You could use a commercial service like [Pusher](http://pusher.com/). Pusher is easy to integrate and fast, but not free. Browser compatibility is great, though.

The options differ primarily in the amount of client support (do you need IE support?) and the amount of Ruby integration you get.